# How to add one audio file on to other one?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, merge, record

I have an audio file of music and i need to record the small clips of songs and add over to the music file at different times. You can understand in that way that I have a long strip of paper and I have to paste small papers on the bigger paper at different positions. 
Please suggest some way.

Let me give the more detail here. Suppose I have 10 small sound clips of 5 seconds each and I have a music file of 50 seconds. So in total I have 11 sound files. Now I have to create one final audio file by adding on the small 10 clips after different times over the music file. like first file should be added at 5.22 second and second file should be added at 10.34 second.

Comment: This is a very generic question, as it stands. You need to be more explicit about what, in the process vaguely described, is currently confusing you. Stating some requirements for your solution would help as well (e.g., tagging it 'iphone' only goes so far).

Comment: An uncompressed audio file is just a series of voltage measurements taken at regular intervals -- from roughly 8000 per second to 44.1Khz.  A stereo file may be two tracks of alternating left and right measurements.  Each measurement is some length -- 8, 12, 16, 24, or 32 bits.  The file has a header that gives info about the file -- data rate, number of channels, number of bits per channel, etc.  "Splicing" would be a matter of stripping off the headers, arranging the sequences of measurements back-to-back, then creating a new header for the combined data.

Comment: @MatthewHall Mathew, I have explained the question further.

Comment: Quite easy to do, once you've cracked the file format.  If the files are compressed, though, it can get a bit messier, since Apple's built-in tools don't seem to handle compression well, at least not on the simulator.

Comment: @HotLicks Can you please elaborate?

Comment: About what?  The file formats are well-documented on the web.  You read the files in, interpret the headers, and then combine the data streams appropriately.  It's just code.

Comment: iOS does have some facilities to help with this, but they don't really help much -- you can just as well "roll your own".

Comment: @Harsh It's still not clear to me whether what you want to do is splice or mix the audio. But I'm not going to be very helpful myself regarding iOS specifics.

Comment: @MatthewHall Suppose I have two mp3 files, a.mp3 of 5 seconds and b.mp3 of 7 seconds and I want to mix them in order to generate c.mp3 of duration 7 secs.

Comment: @Harsh All right, I supposed.  And wrote a novel.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer according to your clarification in the comments:

> Suppose I have two mp3 files, a.mp3 of 5 seconds and b.mp3 of 7
>   seconds and I want to mix them in order to generate c.mp3 of duration
>   7 secs.

As stated in comments, I can't give you any iOS specifics, but I can give you a look at what it will take logically to perform this process, regardless of platform and libraries employed.  I will use simple C++ snippets to demonstrate.  However, it sounds like what you want to do is mix a.mp3 (hereafter A) somewhere into b.mp3 (hereafter B)-- let's saying mixing A onto the beginning of B-- to produce the resultant audio clip C.

Foremost, since you mentioned that they were MP3 files and not WAV or some other uncompressed PCM format such as RAW or AIFF, you'll first need to transform A and B into an uncompressed form such as `S16_LE` PCM (CD audio format-- signed 16-bit integer samples, little endian), which means you'll be working with an array of sample values-- with left and right channels interleaved if stereo audio-- for A and B and therefore C, the last of which may later be optionally re-encoded to MP3 when you're done mixing.

You should use a library to take care of the file encoding/format issues for you, but when using them, they all-- including system interfaces for direct recording or playback-- produce (i.e., when reading) or expect (i.e., when writing) essentially this same basic uncompressed PCM sample stream format. For general development, the ubiquitous `libsndfile` C library is useful for taking care of all of this for you for ~47 file formats, including Ogg Vorbis and FLAC (but no direct MP3 support) in addition to the WAV format variants upon which you should probably be focusing.

For simplicity, we'll only consider monophonic sound clips A and B (i.e., it's just a straight array of sample values for A and B and we don't have to worry about interleaved left/right channels); you can extend the notion to stereo easily by considering each stereo channel independently (A.left mixes with B.left, A.right mixes with B.right) if it matters. If your particular A and B are stereo but C doesn't need to be, you could also simply convert both input audio clips to mono beforehand, depending upon the application.

Further, it is usually easier to work with audio samples as floating-point values, so convert (or, usually, your audio file library does it for you-- `libsndfile` does) the uncompressed sample format to floating-point in the range [-1.0, +1.0], where an absolute value of 1.0 represents the loudest possible sample value and 0.0 represents silence.  These sample values comprise the evolution of an arbitary audio waveform over time (i.e., over the array).

First, you'll need to ensure that you have enough "headroom" (guard against clipping in the output) before mixing. Why? Mixing employs the principle of signal superposition (addition) to combine signals/sounds: we'll be adding A and B together for each overlapping sample, and thus the mixed output samples might "clip" if the corresponding samples' sum from A and B exceeds 1.0 or falls under -1.0.

There are several ways to guard to against clipping, depending upon your respective input levels and whether you want to preserve their volume ratio or simply combine them equally (or whether you're working with stereo and want to use whichever is the loudest channel of A or B as your reference point-- which is the last we'll hear of stereo).

We'll take the simplest route and normalize both A and B's volume to peak at no more than half of full scale (0.5) so that when they're added together, they'll never clip (i.e., no mixed output sample will ever exceed the range [-1.0, +1.0]). If, instead of 2 inputs, there were 3 input audio clips X, Y, and Z that were to be mixed together simultaneously with this method, we'd normalize each to 1/3 of full scale at peak (0.33).

Find the peak value of both A and B, `A_peak` and `B_peak`, by iterating over their respective sample buffers/arrays and determining the maximum sample value in each. [Code to follow.]

Determine a scaling value `A_scale` and `B_scale` for each sample buffer A and B respectively such that their multiplication against the respective peak value yields half-scale. [Code to follow.]

```
A_scale * A_peak == 0.5
B_scale * B_peak == 0.5
```

Ergo:

```
A_scale = 1 / (2 * A_peak)
B_scale = 1 / (2 * B_peak)
```

Now, we could multiply the entire sample buffers A and B by `A_scale` and `B_scale` respectively, and they will be normalized to peak at exactly half-scale each and no mixed sample from the two will ever exceed full-scale.  That is, even if the maximum values of A and B aligned for a sample, their scaled and summed mix output would be exactly 1.0 and never greater. Such a scaling coefficient is often referred to as the "gain."

Again, there are multiple ways to normalize the gain between two or more sample buffers (audio clips) when mixing but this is the simplest and most general for demonstration. Plus, it is easily adapted to mixing N different audio clips together (as noted above) and, with a slight simplification, to real-time mixing of sample *streams* (where the entire audio clip's sample buffer isn't available and sample processing is done in chunks, as is often the case when recording).

Now, we can get down to mixing.

In this case, A (5sec) fits within B (7sec), so we could output the mix directly into B in-place, but for generality, let's output the mix into the separate sample buffer C (7sec), leaving inputs A and B untouched as floating-point sample buffers (perhaps to be reused).

Let `A_len` be the length of A in sample count (which is trivially determined-- the library tells you when you load the file, though fundamentally it's dependent upon only time duration and sample rate), likewise for `B_len` and B, and for the output C, `C_len == B_len`, because `B_len > A_len` in your problem statement.

Allocate C, our mix output:

```
unsigned int C_len = max(A_len, B_len);
double C[] = new double[ C_len ];
```

Find peaks of absolute values of samples in A and B:

```
double A_peak = -1.0, B_peak = -1.0;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < A_len; ++i) A_peak = max( A_peak, fabs(A[i]) );
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < B_len; ++i) B_peak = max( B_peak, fabs(B[i]) );
```

Find half-scale normalized gain of A and B:

```
double A_scale = 1 / ( 2 * A_peak );
double B_scale = 1 / ( 2 * B_peak );
```

Mix A over B into C:

```
assert(A_len <= B_len);
assert(B_len == C_len);

unsigned int x = 0;

for (; x < A_len; ++x)
  C[x] = A_scale * A[x] + B_scale * B[x]; // actual mixing of A and B, finally

for (; x < B_len; ++x)
  C[x] = B_scale * B[x]; // as if A[x] were zero & no abrupt gain change
```

Note that the floating-point buffers A and B are still unchanged after the mix and normalization.

A can just be thought of as zero/silent everywhere where it's not mixed-in.

If we wanted to start mixing A at an arbitrary offset within B (rather than at the start, assumed here), then we'd simply calculate the number of samples that correspond to our time offset (`t_offset` in seconds, `s_offset = t * sample_rate` in integer samples), and start including A in the mix at `x == s_offset` in the above loop constructs.  [Assuming that `s_offset + A_len <= C_len` to prevent overflow.]

One is encouraged to try more application-specific methods of normalizing the mixed inputs, as there are many possibilities.  For example, what if I'd calculated the peak of the sum of samples of A and B instead of calculating peaks for each independently (essentially mixing first and correcting afterward)?  When might this [better] technique not be possible?

Finally, whenever you mix signals, there is always a potential for artifacts at the transition points (e.g., clicks) where the mix starts and ends (e.g., at the point where A ends but B keeps going into C).  This is a relatively low risk here.  However, the general solution for such artifacts is to do short-time fade-ins and fade-outs of entering/leaving inputs to the mix, which eliminates the artifacts by smoothing the mixed waveform and can be done so fast as to not be audible.